# Django how to use npm modules with static/ templates

Tags: django, npm, gulp, frontend, django-staticfiles

I have recently added **npm** to my project in order to keep better track of my js dependencies. Previously I have just been git cloning to my static/vendor folder.

I've also added **gulp** , but have only got it doing hello world things right now. It seems simple enough - it can watch files, minify assets, compile Sass. Eventually I will probably switch to *Webpack*, but gulp is simple and working for now. I don't want to use *django-compressor* or *django-pipeline*.

---

So let's say I run `npm install vis` to pull in visjs. It gets added to `node_modules` and a record is added to `package.json` dependencies.

**A)** Do I reference vis/dist right where it is in node_mods in my template scripts?

```
<script src="/node_modules/vis/dist/min-vis.js' %}"></script>

# right now it's <script src="{% static 'vendor/min-vis.js' %}"></script
```

**B)** Should gulp be listening for changes to package.json dependencies and replicating vis/dist to static/vendor or static/js when it sees changes there?

---

I keep seeing people talking about handling STATICFILE_DIRS when they talk about npm and gulp. Right now mine is just set to the following. Will this change?

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`STATICFILES_DIRS` tells Django where to find all the static assets (which will later be "collected" for a deployment, but we can ignore that for the moment). That setting will need to include wherever you have `gulp` placing the processed assets, or you can have gulp put them into `$BASE_DIR/static` to avoid changing your setting if you prefer.

From there, you should be using the [`static` templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'your_bundled_asset.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Note that if your asset is in a nested directory under the `STATICFILES_DIRS` entry it is under, you may need to prefix that. `{% static 'js/asset.min.js' %}`.

So Django can use the dev location (`$BASE_DIR/static`) or the "collected" location when deployed (`./manage.py collectstatic --noinput` pulls all static files to one location for simplified serving).