# use npm library in django template

Tags: javascript, django

I want to use javascript npm module in `django` template.

In javascript document, it says

`npm install waveform-playlist --save` on cli

and to use this line in code.

`import WaveformPlaylist from "waveform-playlist";`

So, for now I write this script in template.html

```
<script>
import WaveformPlaylist from "waveform-playlist";
</script>
```

this error comes.

```
 Cannot use import statement outside a module (at tracks:96:5)
```

I think some basic idea is wrong?

How can I use this type of javascript?

Comment: you may want to take a look at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325809/django-how-to-use-npm-modules-with-static-templates
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70089451/how-can-i-use-npm-modules-with-django-inside-an-app

Comment: Thank you very much , I decided to use webpack